# How to close FancyBox when popup image with link is clicked?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have a FancyBox, that opens a link when clicked on the popped up image:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    afterShow: function () {
        $(".fancybox-image").wrap("<a href='"+$(this.element).attr('name')+"' target='_blank' />");
    }
});
```

Now, I'd like to close the FancyBox when the photo is clicked so I add `closeClick`:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    closeClick: true,
    afterShow: function () {
        $(".fancybox-image").wrap("<a href='"+$(this.element).attr('name')+"' target='_blank' />");
    }
});
```

This doesn't work. The link opens fine, but the FancyBox doesn't close.

If I remove `aftershow` FancyBox closes just fine.

So how can both be achieved with a click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *chain* several jQuery methods to the same selector, so after `.wrap()` you could chain an `.on()` method where you could bind a `click` *event* that would trigger the `$.fancybox.close()` public method, like :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        // API options
        afterShow: function () {
            $(".fancybox-image")
            // first method
            .wrap("<a href='" + $(this.element).attr('name') + "' target='_blank' />")
            // second method
            .on("click", function () {
                $.fancybox.close(true);
            });
        }
    }); // fancybox
}); // ready
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wtcpnh1s/)**